# How do I make Javascript suitable for the browser side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, browser

I'm currently writing a node.js app which is a simple Snake/Tron style game, however I've written classes that I want to use on the server side and the browser side (maps of pixels). I've got a line for the node side which is:

```
module.exports = Map;
```

But this doesn't work on the browser side (I get a message about module being undefined), so the map doesn't load and my game doesn't draw to the screen.

I have already tried having a line before this like:

```
if (!document)
    module.exports = Map;
```

But this crashes node with "ReferenceError: document is not defined".
 Is there any way I can use the same code on the server side and client side?

Comment: http://css.dzone.com/articles/how-write-and-unit-test/

Comment: The reference error can be solved by using `if typeof document != 'undefined'` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (typeof module !== 'undefined') {
  module.exports = foo;
} else {
  this.foo = foo; // or window.foo
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Browsers dont have the commonJS spec that node does. You can try using something like [Require.js](http://requirejs.org/) which is a module loader. It can be used both client side and in nodejs.

Another option is [Browserify](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify).

Answer (score 0):

For [string.js](http://stringjs.com), I just simply do:

```
if (window) {
  //you are in browser
} else {
  // you are in Node.js
}
```

Hope that helps.